# How to change Model storage to Memory for SQL Server Data Tools project files in MSBuild

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs, msbuild, sql-server-data-tools

I'm running into an issue with MSBuild running SSDT for VS 2012, which I have forced in a .proj used for running the subtree build by the property:

`<PropertyGroup><VisualStudioVersion>11.0</VisualStudioVersion></PropertyGroup>`

When it executes, the build runs fine locally on a "Developer Command Prompt for 2012" cmd window using msbuild from command-line. However, during a TFS build MSBuild will emit the issue for a random .sqlproj that was built:

`C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v11.0\SSDT\Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.SqlTasks.targets (513): The process cannot access the file 'D:\Builds\...\Sources\obj\...\Release\Model.xml' because it is being used by another process.`

(imagine there's some other directory paths there for the ... that I've snipped for privacy)

Other than killing my build performance by passing msbuild `/m:1` to restrict to one "CPU", trying to avoid the contention on the `Model.xml` file that the `SqlBuildTask` creates at the end of its execution, how can I avoid this issue? I've tried to find details online but MSDN and search engines are failing to find something that is equivalent to the sqlpackage.exe parameter, `Storage=Memory`, which suggests it doesn't make the `Model.xml` file and instead uses memory.

For reference, I am generating a .dacpac output from my build such that I can use it to publish to a any database later and upgrade it to latest (using aforementioned sqlpackage.exe on the command-line with the `/a:Publish` command).

Comment: is the output of the sql task listed as an input to your later targets

Comment: No, but I am thinking I will try to investigate how the obj output directory is being set. I may be able to fix this by changing it to not be one directory up from the project specific intermediate output directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the following MSDN article useful in fixing this issue: [Common MSBuild Project Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb629394.aspx)

In my project file I had the following (snipping out the non-relevant bits here such as the files in the project in `ItemGroup`'s):

```
<Project DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" ToolsVersion="4.0">
  <Import Project="$(DepotRoot)\internal\infrastructure\build\BuildDbProj.prop" />
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Name>FooDatabase</Name>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

I altered the prop file such that it now has an IntermediateOutputPath (the other bits were already there), which now looks like:

```
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
    <Import Project="Build.prop" />
    <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputPath>$(FullOutputPath)Databases\$(Name)\</OutputPath>
    <IntermediateOutputPath>$(FullIntermediateOutputPath)\$(Name)</IntermediateOutputPath>
    <DeploymentPath>$(FullOutputPath)Deployment\DB\$(Name)\</DeploymentPath>
        <DeploymentContentPath>$(DeploymentPath)Content\</DeploymentContentPath>
    </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

The relevant bits of the `Build.prop` file look like:

```
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <BranchRoot>$([MSBuild]::GetDirectoryNameOfFileAbove($(MSBuildProjectDirectory), branch.root))\</BranchRoot>
    <BranchingFolderStructure>$(BranchRoot.Replace($(DepotRoot)\internal\, ``))</BranchingFolderStructure>
    <BaseIntermediateOutputPath Condition="'$(BaseIntermediateOutputPath)' == ''">$(DepotRoot)\obj\$(BranchingFolderStructure)</BaseIntermediateOutputPath>
    <FullIntermediateOutputPath Condition="'$(FullIntermediateOutputPath)' == ''">$(BaseIntermediateOutputPath)$(Configuration)\$(Platform)</FullIntermediateOutputPath>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

What this now does is redirect the Model.xml to output to the `D:\Builds\...\Sources\obj\...\Debug\AnyCPU\FooDatabase` directory, where `FooDatabase` is the `Name` property in the database project. Now I don't need to change the MSBuild to use `BuildInParallel` set to False, etc.